# Unable to get jstl requestScope variables set by servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

I am learning `JSTL` for the first time and am using jstl-1.2.jar, Tomcat 7 and latest version of Java in Eclipse IDE.

I am trying to simply print out rows of a table for each item in a list. The objects in the list have their public attributes set in a `servlet` which forwards the list to the index.jsp page where I am trying to do the printing.

Here is my servlet:

```
import jstl.Employee;

@WebServlet("/HomeServlet")
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setId(1); emp1.setName("John");emp1.setRole("Developer");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setId(2); emp2.setName("Jane");emp2.setRole("Manager");
        empList.add(emp1);empList.add(emp2);

        request.setAttribute("empList", empList);
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And the index.jsp page where I attempt to loop over the list and print out the object variables which are publicly accessible properties:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Home Page</title>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<style>
table,th,td
{border:1px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <%-- Using JSTL forEach and out to loop a list and display items in table --%>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Role</th></tr>
        <c:forEach items="${requestScope.empList}" var="emp">
            <tr><td><c:out value="${emp.id}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${emp.name}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${emp.role}"></c:out></td></tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently when I load the page only the table headers are displayed and not the two rows why is this?

EDIT: 
added Employee class:

```
package jstl;


public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String role;
    public Employee() {
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

EDIT: These are the jstl.jars I'm using:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<c:forEach items="${empList}" var="emp">`.

Also, you need to access your page through the servlet. In your case that would be `/HomeServlet`. If you are accessing your page through `/index.jsp`, the list will not be created and therefore can't be found by your JSP file.

Comment: You are accessing the page through the servlet and not by just typing "localhost/index.jsp" in the address bar, right?

Comment: No I am accessing the index.jsp page only `http://localhost:8080/jstl/index.jsp`.

Comment: You should access your page through the servlet, otherwise the list will not be set to the request. You have to configure the servlet by adding it into web.xml.

Comment: So the servlet becomes my new index page or Welcome-file in the web.xml?

Comment: There should be a web.xml file in the WEB-INF directory of your application. If you just created the "jstl" directory under your tomcat/webapps directory, you might want to read into [this](http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/eclipse-create-deployable-war-file-for-java-web-application).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know, that you can skip the XML-stuff with tomcat 7. You can already access your servlet: `http://localhost:8080/jstl/HomeServlet`

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just wondering when I type www.mysite.com the welcome-file needs to be the servlet now instead of the index.jsp.

Comment: Yes. If you want your list be available in your jsp, and the jsp is your welcome-file, you need to set the servlet as your new welcome-file. Also, I edited my answer - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.empList}" var="emp">
```

it should be

```
<c:forEach items="${empList}" var="emp">
```

Comment: I modified it to `<c:forEach items="empList" var="emp">`..have you tried this ?

Comment: Yes that gives this error: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not found on type java.lang.String`

Comment: So it is giving error to `<c:out value="${emp.id}">`..id is integer right ?

Comment: Yes `id` is an int. I added the Employee class in my question. It gives the error for the Strings too..

Comment: Try using - <c:forEach items="${empList}" var="emp">